# Positioning images loaded through AJAX with

Tags: jquery, dom

I am trying to load images using a search query, and then position them using the jQuery Blocks It plugin ([BlocksIt.js](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/)). This is the relevant javascript:

```
    <script>
            function getResults(query, max, $selector)
            {
                $selector.html("Loading...");
                $.getJSON('/search', {query: query, max: max}, function(data) {
                    var items = data;
                    $selector.html("");
                    for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i)
                        $selector.html($selector.html()+"<div class='img-holder' ><img  class='search-image' src='"+ data[i] +"' /></div>");
                });

                $selector.waitForImages({
                    finished: function(){
                        $selector.BlocksIt({
                            numOfCol: 4,
                            offsetX: 1,
                            offsetY: 1
                        });
                    },
                    waitForAll: true
                });
                $selector.css({height: '500px', overflow: 'auto'});
            }
            jQuery(function($) {
                $('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {
                    getResults($('#db-search').val(), 20, $('.search-results'));
                    $('.search-results').BlocksIt({
                        numOfCol: 4,
                        offsetX: 1,
                        offsetY: 1
                    });
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });

</script>
```

And the DOM goes like this:

```
<div class='row-fixed'>
                <div class='span4'>
                    <form data-async class="search-form navbar-search pull-left" action='/search'>
                        <input type="text" id='db-search' class="search-query" name='query' placeholder="Search" />
                        <input type='hidden' name='max' value=20 />
                    </form>
                    <div class="search-results" style="width: 100%; height:500px; position:relative;">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am calling the BlocksIt() function twice, once before, and once after images are loaded. I tried doing it only once as well (both before and after image load) , but it doesn't seem to work. The images are displayed with a width equaling 100% of the width of `div.search-results`. But when I call the function in Chrome Dev Tools Console Window, after the image has been loaded, as:

```
$('.search-results').BlocksIt({
                    numOfCol: 4,
                    offsetX: 1,
                    offsetY: 1
                });
```

the images get aligned and resized perfectly. Please help me in doing it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This code will never be invoked!

```
jQuery(function($) {
     $('form[data-async]').live('submit', function(event) {
          getResults($('#db-search').val(), 20, $('.search-results'));
          $('.search-results').BlocksIt({
          numOfCol: 4,
          offsetX: 1,
          offsetY: 1
           });
         event.preventDefault();
      });
});
```

Comment: This indeed does get invoked when I hit return on the search box. (Confirmed by calling `console.log()`). And of course, if this was not getting invoked, then no AJAX call would have been made, and no images would have been loaded.

Comment: ok! But it looks so bad that my first shoot was to that code!